# Media Queries are really touchy

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, media-queries

On my website I have several different items (like a shopping website would have items displayed in a grid). Each item has a specific width % and height % depending on the screen size. At 1024 and above my site operates appropriately with a clean grid but when scaled down to 768 or below the grid breaks.

What I would like is each item to look nice and in a grid like fashion. And in Google Chrome at 1024px and above it looks perfect.

[Here is the perfect view in chrome]

[image]

[Here is the slightly zoomed in broken view]

[image]

You can see that the grid has broken out of alignment.

Here is the code that I use for each item but it seems to break even though I am using Media Queries. Maybe I just don't know how to use Media Queries properly? Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
#content {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    margin:1.5% auto;
    }

#item {
    width:40%;
    height:40%;
    padding:0.5%;
    margin:1%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    float:left;
    }
```

Below are the only media queries I am using at the moment.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {
    #item {
        width:17%;
        height:60%;
        }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #item {
        width:22%;
        height:50%;
        }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {width: 98%; margin: 0 auto 1.5% auto;}
    #content {
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
        margin:1.5% auto;
        }

    #item {
        width:40%;
        height:40%;
        padding:0.5%;
        margin:1%;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        float:left;
        }
    footer {width:98%; margin: 1.5% auto 0 auto;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    header {width: 98%; margin: 0 auto 1.5% auto;}
    #content {
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
        margin:0.5% auto 0.5% auto;
        }

    #item {
        width:100%;
        height:30%;
        padding:0.5%;
        margin:0.5% auto 0.5% auto;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        }
    footer {width:100%}
}
```

-Luke

Comment: Could you please show your media queries? I do have a doubt about the issue being queries in pixels rather than em's. That usually is the case.

Comment: I've added my media queries to the post. Note that I am using % and not px or em.

Comment: Your queries read `320px` as opposed to an em value (say `32em` if your em base is 10px). I personally go `html { font-size: 62.5%; /*10px*/ }` to use `32em` (or `32rem`) -- its simple math and uses em units. Try this and let me know.

Comment: I have changed my code to this but my grid is now broken at 1024px. I'm not sure I am fully understanding using em's for media queries. Please provide me with some websites that I can read to get a better grasp.

Comment: I suggest any simple research would provide details on how they work. This being said, if the design messes up at or around 1024px, try working with 1012, it'll probably solve your issue.

Comment: @PubliDesign Are you sure that 62.5% for a font size results in 10px? It doesn't on my computer...

Comment: Basic/standard font-size is usually 16px. You could play it safe and go `html{ font-size: 10px; }`. From there on, you're guaranteed it will be a perfect fit.

Comment: Right. So why would you write 62.5% if you want a font size of 10px? What you're doing now is take the user's preferred size (that they may have meticulously chosen in the settings) and display the page at a fraction of it. That is illogical! No, really there are only two options: either you don't change the font size from the user's preferences at all (so the page will show at their optimal size), or you choose a font size yourself (in this case, 10px). It makes no sense to take a percentage and then just assume it will come out the size you wanted.

Comment: Mr. Lister can you recommend how to go about this? I got media queries working finally but have set font-size to 16px. Should I be setting the font-size at all?

Comment: Like I explained to Publi Design, that depends on what you want. You can either leave the font size as is, or choose your own. Your call. Just don't assume that the user hasn't changed anything in the browser settings. Don't assume that 62.5% of the user's preferred size is 10px! And if the user has, for instance, a minimum font size of 16px, then if you set the page's size to 8px, everything will still be 16px for the user, even headers like `h1`.